# WebClient Proxy Https Issue

Tags: c#, ssl, webclient

I've read allot about issues over SSL using proxy and i think its cause of the ssl certificate validation. But i have tested different methods to set it to always accept SSL without success. My code works fine for HTTP but for HTTPS it "hangs"on connect and then fails.

My code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

string response;
            try
            {
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    var ProxyA = "192.168.0.103:8888".Split(':'); 
                    string PHost = ProxyA[0];
                    int PPort = Int32.Parse(ProxyA[1]);
                    wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(PHost, PPort);              
                    response = wc.DownloadString("https://www.mittip.se"); 

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the website www.mittip.se does not work via https try these links.

[http](http://www.mittip.se/)

[https](https://www.mittip.se/)

This isn't due to the certitifate, it's simply a case of the server not listening for https, unfortunately there is nothing you do in the code can make the website respond on https.

Comment: Thank you! The sample code above was just some test code i did while playing with the SSL Certs and like you say it does not work over SSL. Now i tested my old code with 
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
And it worked fine! Thank you so much! My bad misstake!